# Mat Paginator issue

Tags: angular7

I am using mat table below structure in my project.

```
**<mat-paginator></mat-paginator>
<mat-table></mat-table>
<mat-paginator></mat-paginator>**

In my ts file look like

 **@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;**


 **Actual problem is first one paginator is working fine and trigger events correctly.
 bottom mat paginator is not working and event is not triggered ,also page,pageIndex is not 
refelecting from first paginator**
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild` queries only one component reference. But you have two components in your view. So, you have to query both the components separately, as shown below.

`<mat-paginator #topPageinator></mat-paginator>
<mat-table></mat-table>
<mat-paginator #bottomPageinator></mat-paginator>`

`@ViewChild('topPageinator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('bottomPageinator') paginator: MatPaginator;`

**OR**

You can use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`

`@ViewChildren(MatPaginator) paginators:  QueryList<MatPaginator>;`

Comment: above two solution is not working and also event also not triggered

Comment: Can you share the exact code of the view(html file) and the logic (ts file)?